# SharePoint 2013 - Federated Search + Open Search + Making refiners work

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, search, federated-search

I have configured Federated Search in SharePoint 2013 with a result source using OpenSearch Protocol. This result source can be anything like bing, google, twitter etc.

E.g. of approach - http://richardstk.com/2013/11/08/sharepoint-2013-federated-search-to-bing/

The approach works fine without any problem. However, I do not get any refiners in my search results.

I understand this is due to the fact that Open Search format does not return any extra meta-data (like Author, Modified date etc.) which can be used or consumed by SharePoint for creating refiners.

Is there any way of achieving this?